# UDP stream into webRTC

Tags: javascript, networking, udp, webrtc

I am just starting to learn web/network programming (hence not sure what information is relevant), but my goal is to play a stream video acquired by a computer X to a webpage hosted on computer Y as close to realtime as possible. I currently have an awkward solution that is just about ok for my needs whereby the video acquired on computer X is sent to computer Y through a UDP socket. This data is then sent (via ffmpeg) into a 'fake webcam' created using v4l2loopback which is then read using the getUserMedia(). Doing this I have a choppy-ish video that lags less than 2s.

My question, simply, is whether it is possible to read in the UDP stream directly in the webRTC framework (somehow, and if so how) rather than the going awkwardly through the webcam.

Comment: Do you have control over computer Y and the software that produces the stream? If yes, why go the extra route over UDP and not send it from X to Y via WebRTC in the first place?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I don't really have control at that end.

Comment: You could build a UDP server which receives the data from computer X and then, via WebRTC, pipes it to your desired peer (computer Y in your example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that *directly* with WebRTC since it doesn't expose a raw socket but your options are:

#### Convert it to an HLS live stream

- Convert the UDP stream (I assume RTMP? What is ffmpeg outputting?) to an HLS stream on your server via [`nginx-hls-rtmp`](https://docs.peer5.com/guides/setting-up-hls-live-streaming-server-using-nginx/).
- Use [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js) to play said video.

#### Convert it to a DataChannel and send it over SCTP

- Set up a media streaming WebRTC server for example [wrtc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wrtc)
- Connect to the web client via WebRTC (for example [simple peer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer) can help).
- Set up a DataChannel that works over SCTP (implemented with libsctp over udp in Chrome Safari and Firefox).
- Send the data on the data channel and decode it there.

#### Connect directly from X to Y via WebRTC

- You can also set up a WebRTC server and connect ffmpeg to that
- Open a Media channel between the WebRTC 'server' peer and the client.
- Stream the video.

---

Of these options - the first is *by far* the simplest. The disadvantage is that it isn't very suitable for low latency streaming + there is some overhead.

I recommend you start with it and work your way up.

Comment: Hi thanks this is exactly what I needed. What kind of latencies would you expect with each of these solutions. I had already tried the HLS live stream but found it was substantially slower than the perhaps  more awkward option

Comment: HLS - reasonably no less than 4-6 seconds of delay, Over a DataChannel - probably 2-4 and WebRTC is the fastest but most complex. I would start with HLS unless you have interactivity requirements since it is easiest in terms of going through firewalls and caching. WebRTC really works well with 1 on 1 video. Another thing you can try is LHLS (like twitch) https://medium.com/@periscopecode/introducing-lhls-media-streaming-eb6212948bef

Answer (score 0):

in Windows you can use AVObjects directshow filter
it support UDP to webrtc.
it also supports stun servers

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you use a WebRTC library. [libdatachannel](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel) (I'm the original author) will let you open a WebRTC peer connection with a video track and send the RTP packets directly in the track provided the codec is H264 or VP8.